# javascript to C# code Array implementation

Tags: c#, generics

this is javascript code, I want to change it into C# code, same as this is, b/c again I'll change it to javascript object

```
data: [['2-2010',45.0],['IE', 26.8],[ 'Chrome',12.8],['Safari',8.5],['Opera',6.2],['Others', 0.7]]
```

actually I'm writing a wrapper which will take values in C# language and then through json serialize I'll convert the code into json.

I can't do it like this, b/c at the time of creating json it would be some thing like

**C#**

```
class dataArray
{
  public string browserId;
  public double percentRate;
}
```

**JS** Generated by the above class but not useable for me b/c of the variable browser and percentRate

```
dataArray = {browser: 'chrome', 'percentRate':30.3}
```

I was expecting something like this `List<string,double>`  but it would never work :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `List` of `object` arrays to get the output that you're looking for.  I used JSON.net for the example code below.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<object[]> kvp = new List<object[]>()
        {
            new object[] {"2-2010", 45},
            new object[] {"IE", 26.8},
            new object[] {"Chrome", 12.8},
            new object[] {"Safari", 8.5}
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(kvp);

        Console.WriteLine(json);

        //deserialize it to a List<object[]>
        var json2 = "[[\"2-2010\",45.0],[\"IE\", 26.8],[\"Chrome\",12.8],[\"Safari\",8.5]]";
        var kvp2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object[]>>(json2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you'd better have an array of dictionaries, each dictionary will be equal to the object and its key and values will be his property and value

Comment: Why do you advocate an array of Dictionaries rather than simply a Dictionary<string, float>?

Answer (score 0):

You could use anonymous types which looks a lot like the JS code, but without single quoutes around percentRate. You could also use Tuples, which is `Tuple<string, float>` and is basically a pair of values. Multidimensional or jagged arrays are another option.